# open pdf file from javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, mime

How can I return an Open/Save dialog box to a PDF file on the server using only javascript?

I don't want the current pages location to change, however.   Do I need to trigger an Iframe?

Comment: The only thing I can make of that is an illogical thing to do, could you explain your question in some more detail?

Comment: I've got a one page application w/ complex UI via ExtJS.  Currently reports are firing by opening up another tab in the browser.  Instead, I want to fire an Open/Save dialog via javascript without opening a new tab, and without changing the location of the current tab.  I've seen it done before, but can't find the code.

Comment: Why not simply have the webpage download the file, and let the browser handle popping up the "Open? Save?" dialog?

Comment: I don't want the page to change.  It's not a webpage, but an application that is loaded into the current url and maintained by javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can open a file with the `window.open` command. The prompt would depend on the user's settings as to what the default action should be.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://linktoPDF', 'NewWin');">link</a>
```

Comment: ya, that's what i already have.  What I'm trying to do is transparently show it via an iframe (or a better solution) without opening a new window/tab.

Comment: Remove the `, 'NewWin'` portion and it will prompt in same window. The popup is a dialog, so it will not show inside an iFrame, as it will always popup.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you'd have to use an iframe for that.  You could use the style `visible:false;` or maybe set the `height` and `width` to `1px`, but I don't know if `display:none;` would work.  Know that for some browsers, and iframe adds to the history, but it sounds like that isn't a problem.

Comment: ya, cause the main requirement is that the client WANTS an open/save dialog always.  They never want the PDF to open up inside of the browser.  Maybe this isn't possible?

Comment: That's only possible when sending the HTTP header, which you can't modify with javascript.